# export_png Bokeh with all layers

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I try to make bokeh plot and export it in PNG. When i add legend layer it export empty image and i don't know why.

And when i exportinf png, i always watch this messege : "WARNING - The webdriver raised a TimeoutException while waiting for a 'bokeh:idle' event to signify that the layout has rendered. Something may have gone wrong."

on the first pic you can see coorrect export file, on the second - fail pic

Maybe i need to union my layers< but i don't know why

When i comment p.add_layout(new_legend, 'below') it export correctly, but legend located on my graph.

```
p.add_layout(new_legend, 'below')
p.tools.append(hover)

show(p)
export_png(p, filename=dir + "testoviy.png")
save(p)
```

I expect that the graph will be built and export correctly and the legend will be below the graph

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS6Hp.png)

[bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwyS8.png)

Comment: Soory i can add only bad pic

Comment: It's possible there is a bug or some corner case to address. To investigate, a *complete* example to reproduce will be required, along with full relevant (bokeh, browser, platform) version information.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. When i using xaxis range - i have to make height of my figure bigger. [figure params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sdvl.png)

Or i can delete range of my yaxis range.